# What features should I look for in a mini knife?

Tags: knives

I'm looking for a small or mini knife for when I don't have a normal sized knife with me. I don't need it for self-defense, but just for cutting things in normal day usage.

What features should I look for in a very small/mini knife?

Comment: Hi Municial and welcome to TGO. Please ask only one question per post, you are mixing several different ones here. Also "Which is better" without a clear use case or requirements isn't a very useful question, as it is opinion-based.

Comment: I still doubt that "normal day usage", "cutting things" and explicitly not fighting is detailed enough to give a targeted and characteristics based answer to "which one is better[?]" - lets see what the "knife-experts" have to say about it though.

Comment: @imsodin what do you meant?

Comment: Lets continue this in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68532/discussion-on-question-which-one-is-better-sogs-snarl-or-crkts-rsk-mk5-or-bro

Comment: Why choose that style over a convention folding pocket knife? Those two are very similar both would be suitable for mundane everyday "opening a box" type of tasks. Both are similar chromoly steel. Both come with a kydex sheath. Personally i would still rather carry a folding pocket knife that a mini blade such as those in a sheath. If your set on that type of blade you might also check out the 5.11 "wharn for duty". similar blade profile in a folder.

Comment: what is a normal size knife, and what is a mini knife, and how is it different from a folding knife?

Comment: @njzk2 mainly I meant a small fixed blade knife that can be fit in pocket, you can search something like **SOG Snarl** and you'll know what I'm meaning

Comment: It seems like you know what you want as far as the type. If I were you I would consider what steel you want? Are you going to be using it in situations like trying to pry things up off something? Do you want an easy to sharpen knife or would you rather it be difficult but rarely need sharpened? High Carbon steel is really good for utility knives, it has a lot of strength but it can be brittle. For example I made a couple of knives from S90V Steel and they hold an edge really well but I have had tips break pretty easily. If you use something like 1095 steel it's very easy to sharpen.

Comment: See this link for steel
http://knifeinformer.com/discovering-the-best-knife-steel/

Comment: What types of things do you cut in "normal day usage"?  Some people open letters all day long, others cut open coconuts...

Answer (score 2):

While I'm unsure on what exactly is a small/mini knife for you I'm going to propose something nonetheless:

### Get a Swiss Army Knife.

[image]

They come in [all kinds of different sizes](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-V5f2EUC3_ZA/VKoROxJgBRI/AAAAAAAAASU/j_YwxQtRFF4/s1600/SAK%2BSizing%2Bchart.PNG), so you should be able to find one that fits your idea of what a 'mini' knife is.

Furthermore you can pick among countless different models with all kinds of extras. You can thus **tailor** the knife exactly to what 'normal day usage' means for you - e.g. look through the [range of models](https://www.swissarmy.com/us/en/Swiss-Army-Knives/cms/swissarmyknives-main) here for a version that is equipped with the tools that you think will come in handy.

As an example: some tools that I have found very useful in the past in an 'every day' setup: cork screw, cap opener, can opener, toothpick tweezers, scissors, various screwdrivers, awl, ...

Comment: That's not a mini knife,this is a mini knife https://www.amazon.com/Grand-Way-Small-Pocket-Knife/dp/B01CDJYT98/ref=sr_1_4?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1548257996&sr=1-4&keywords=mini+knife

Comment: @JamesJenkins Before I edited the plink out, this https://www.amazon.com/ideas/amzn1.account.AEECRLCWVANOE7WWQLD2TGKT73ZQ/2XEI8FU0OLG4R is what the OP was asking about

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh The linked Swiss Army knives start at a (folded) length of 58mm, the one you linked at the top comes in at 60mm. How does that make yours 'more mini'?

Comment: Why don't you look at the knife the OP was asking about?

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh, Sorry, I can't see any specific knife mentioned in the question above. Was it edited?

Comment: Second comment on the answer

Answer (score 1):

It needs a handle that can be securely held by the size hand of the user.The blade won't be useful if one can't keep hold well enough. Also since it is small it will be easier to cut with it if it is very sharp.That way less leverage is required.